# PHP/MongoDB: update a value in an array

Tags: php, mongodb

I have the following mongodb object:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157"),
   "messages": {
     "0": {
       "toUname": "Eamorr3",
       "fromUname": "Eamorr2",
       "time": 1292606586,
       "id": "ABCDZZZ",
       "subject": "asdf",
       "message": "asdf",
       "read": 0   //I want to change this to 1!
    },
    "1": {
       "toUname": "Eamorr1",
       "fromUname": "Eamorr3",
       "time": 1292606586,
       "id": "EFGHZZZ",
       "subject": "asdf2",
       "message": "asdf2",
       "read": 0
    }
  },
   "uname": "Eamorr3"
}
```

How do I set "read" to 1 where id=ABCDZZZZ? I'm using PHP.

I've tried the following command:

```
$driverInboxes->update(array('uname'=>$uname),array('$set'=>array('messages'=>array('id'=>$id,'read'=>'1'))));
```

But when I do this, overwriting occurs and I get:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157"),
   "messages": {
     "id": "j7zwr2hzx14d3sucmvp5",
     "read": "1"
  },
   "uname": "Eamorr3"
}
```

I'm totally stuck. Any help much appreciated.

Do I need to pull the entire array element, modify and and push it back in again?

Many thanks in advance,

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB update nested array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261521/mongodb-update-nested-array)

Comment: Actually right now its possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261521/mongodb-update-nested-array

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you read your command, you're actually saying: *"UPDATE WHERE uname = Eamorr3 SET messages equal to this array (id=blah,read=1)"*

When you do a `$set` on `messages`, you're basically instructing it to take your array as the new value.

However, it looks like you're trying to update a specific message as read which is just a little more complex. So there are two hurdles here:

**1: You're actually updating `messages.0.read`**

If you do `array('$set' => array( 'messages.0.read' => 1 ) )`, you will update the correct element. Follow that chain, `messages` is a javascript object and you want to update the property `0`. The property `0` is itself a javascript object which contains the property `read` which you want to update.

Can you see how you're updating `messages.0.read`?

This brings us to problem #2.

**2: the `0` is a problem for you**

If you look at the way you've structured the data in Mongo, the messages object is really sub-par. The "0" and "1" are currently acting as "ids" and they're not very useful. Personally, I would structure your objects with the actual IDs in place of "0" or "1".

So your objects would look like the following:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("4d0b9c7a8b012fe287547157"),
   "messages": {
     "ABCDZZZ": {
       "toUname": "Eamorr3",
       "fromUname": "Eamorr2",
       "time": 1292606586,
       "subject": "asdf",
       "message": "asdf",
       "read": 0   //I want to change this to 1!
    }
  },
   "uname": "Eamorr3"
}
```

Now you're update command becomes this:

`array('$set' => array( 'messages.ABCDZZZ.read' => 1 ) )`

This structure makes it much easier to update a specific message or a specific portion of a message.

Comment: Hey, I was thinking of restructuring like the way you mentioned. I think this is probably the best way to go. Otherwise, I'm going to have to look through the entire array, find the object index, and update.

Comment: Also take a look at [$elemMatch](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Dot+Notation+%28Reaching+into+Objects%29#DotNotation%28ReachingintoObjects%29-Matchingwith%24elemMatch)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to keep the array structure for various purposes, you can use the [Positional operator](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Updating#Updating-The%24positionaloperator).  This enables you to take advantage of array features ($pop,$push,etc) while simultaneously being able to update elements which are in an unknown array position.